# Dhtmlx Sceduler hightlight hours

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I like to ask if DHTMLX Scheduler can  "HIGHLIGHT" or "MARK" hours .

Because it only allow me to hightlight whole day.

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({start_date: new Date(2018,02,19), end_date: new Date(2018,02,20), css: "yellow_section" });
```

I am tying to do is show a hour RANGE in which represent like a employeee working hours.

Sample is like this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {timeLineName}_cell_class event to add custom CSS to your cells based on a condition. You can find the documentation for this event [here](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_%7Btimelinename%7D_cell_class_template.html).

Here's an example where I use it to add a css class to all cells of determined day, but you can change the condition to add custom CSS to determined hours range:

```
scheduler.templates.MyScheduler_cell_class = function(evs, date, section){
    //---- change the condition in the line bellow ----
    if (date.valueOf() == new Date('2015-11-21').valueOf()){ 
        return "custom-css-class-here";
    }
    return "";
}
```